# TypeScript compatability with Luxon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, momentjs, luxon

I'm going through some old code that uses moment.js and are now moving over to luxon. However, I face some problem when using luxon in conjunction with Typescript. Here's an example:

```
interface ColumnProps {
  day: Moment
  isPast: boolean
  onPostClick: PublishPostCardProps['onClick']
  posts: PublishEvent[]
}
```

`day` is currently typed as  `Moment`. Is there something similar for luxon? I was thinking about using `date` But that didn't work. Grateful for any insights :)

Cheers

Comment: Have you had a chance to review the [types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/luxon) for this library? These are the types mentioned in the [installation instructions](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/install.html#types). I'd review the types, try using those types, then update your question if you still see issues. Yes, you wouldn't use `Moment` type in Luxon.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried that and cast "day" to "DateTime" as that is the class name in datetime.d.ts. Later in the code I use "DateTime.toSeconds(p.utc_timestamp).toLocal().day" and get the error "Property 'toSeconds' does not exist on type 'typeof DateTime'" Not really sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you please use something like stackblitz to create an example project with Luxon and the types installed as well as the operation you are trying to do that gives you can error

Comment: That being said, [toSeconds](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/luxon/src/datetime.d.ts#L1053) is not a static method. You would need to call it on an instance of `DateTime`, not `DateTime` class itself. `DateTime.toSeconds()` would only work if it was a `static` method. On the other hand `DateTime.now().toSeconds()` or `DateTime.utc(1982, 5, 25).toSeconds()` or  similar would work. Please update your question with exactly the type of operation you are trying to do, an live example would help also.

Comment: I think some of the `DateTime` class members are not in the TypeScript definitions, or `npm` loaded an older version. I my case, `now` is not present on the `DateTime` class - yet it is present in the online documentation!

Comment: Using `DateTime` is the solution. If you have problems with this, update/create a new question. If the Luxon definitions are out of date, file a bug report. With interface declaration merging you can work around this until the bug is fixed, but I have my suspicions that you're doing something wrong with the DateTime class. All mentioned examples in this thread work perfectly fine for me.

Comment: For example, `DateTime.now().toSeconds()` works without error for me.

Answer (score 1):

If someone's still having issues (like I did) with Luxon and Typescript, I created **ts-luxon** which solves all the problems!

link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-luxon)

install via `npm install ts-luxon` and **no other deps required** (while luxon has separate typings)

My code is aligned with Luxon and I made improvements (mostly performance refactors) where possible!

Also I included custom typings for **Intl** to avoid type issues due to the different versions of ES (es2020, esnext, etc.)